# Why can a magnetic dipole have an energy in the magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy, magnetic-moment, dipole

It is well known that the energy of a magnetic dipole in the magnetic field is given by
$$
V = - \vec \mu \cdot \vec B
$$
But I wonder how there can be a concept of energy at all.
You can imagine the magnetic dipole as being generated by a circular current and then the Lorentz force given by
$$
\vec F = q \vec v \times \vec B
$$
acts on each charged particle, which immediately implies that no work is done, since
$$
W = \int \vec F \cdot \mathrm{d} \vec r = \int (q \vec v \times \vec B) \cdot \mathrm{d} \vec r
$$
and $\vec v \parallel \mathrm{d} \vec r$.
Therefore, I do not see how one could come up with the concept of a potential energy.

Comment: Great question! A classic explanation is given [here](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_15.html).

Answer (score 1):

In the integral equation for $W$ the $d\vec{r}$ is not the line element along the path of the current, is the is the displacement of the object.  So, when we consider the rotational motion of the current loop $d\vec{r} \perp \vec{v}$

Answer (score 0):

A current loop has a magnetic moment:

$$ \mu = IA $$

With potential energy in a magnetic field:

$$ U = \mu B = IAB $$

So the energy change in flipping it is:

$$ \Delta U = 2U = 2IAB $$

In the case of your rotating charges with:

$$ I = qv $$

if you flip the loop, an EMF is generated:

$$ V = \frac{\Delta \Phi}{\Delta t} $$

where the flux is

$$ \Phi = BA $$

and the change in flux is:

$$ \Delta\Phi = 2\Phi = 2BA $$

The power required to keep the current going is:

$$ P = IV = 2BAI/\Delta t $$

(where $\Delta t$ is the time to flip the loop).

The total work done is:

$$ W = P\Delta t = 2BAI = \Delta U $$

So the work is against the magnetic field, it's against the induced electric field.